# Python Runtime Error on running T-Test

Tags: python, c++, numpy

I am calling a python function to calculate "t-test" from my C++ code. The function call is made as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Python.h"
#include "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h"

#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\"PATH_TO_MOD\")");
    PyObject *pName = PyString_FromString("tmpPyth");
    PyObject *pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);


    double arr[] ={9.74219, 10.2226, 8.7469, 8.69791, 9.96442, 9.96472, 9.37913, 9.75004};
    double arr1[] ={9.74219, 10.2226, 8.7469, 8.69791, 9.96442, 9.96472, 9.37913, 9.75004};

    PyObject *lst = PyList_New(8);
    PyObject *lst1 = PyList_New(8);
    // if (!lst)
    //     return NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        PyObject *num = PyFloat_FromDouble(arr[i]);
        PyObject *num1 = PyFloat_FromDouble(arr1[i]);
        PyList_SET_ITEM(lst, i, num);
        PyList_SET_ITEM(lst1, i, num1);
    }

    PyObject *pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, lst);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, lst1);

    if (pModule != NULL) {
        PyObject *pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "blah");

        if(pFunc != NULL){
            PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Module path provided may be wrong. Module not found.\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And my python module is defined as follows:

```
import numpy
import scipy
import matplotlib

from scipy import stats
def blah(baseline, follow_up):
    paired_sample  = stats.ttest_rel(baseline , follow_up )
    print "The t-statistic is %.3f and the p-value is %.3f." % paired_sample
```

Now when i try to run this I get the following runtime exception:

```
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py:3458: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  t = np.divide(dm, denom)
```

But if I explicitly define a list and try and execute the "t-test" function it runs just fine. The running function definition is as follows:

```
import numpy
import scipy
import matplotlib

from scipy import stats

    def blah():
        baseline = [9.74219, 10.2226, 8.7469, 8.69791, 9.96442, 9.96472, 9.37913, 9.75004]
        follow_up = [9.94227,9.46763,8.53081,9.43679,9.97695,10.4285,10.159,8.86134]
        paired_sample  = stats.ttest_rel(baseline , follow_up )
        print "The t-statistic is %.3f and the p-value is %.3f." % paired_sample
```

I am assuming that I am making some mistake in defining the lists being passed to the python script but can not figure out what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing that jumps at me from reading your description, so it looks sound. Just for curiosity, you call `blah()` and the error is in `numpy.stats()`, what are the the values that arrive in `blah()`? Use `print repr(baseline)` and `print repr(follow_up)` to output their representations. That said, why do you still use Python 2? Numpy at least is also available in current Pythons.

Comment: Hmm, maybe a dumb question, but did you consider using the pre-existing [t-tests from scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) instead of re-implementing them?

Answer (score 0):

`arr1` in your c++ code is identical to `arr`, hence the divide by zero. Since `baseline` and `follow_up` in your python code are different you do not get an error.

For larger arrays you would not want to marshal them through python lists, but instead send the arrays directly to python.  I've modified your code above to do this:

```
-- pyfromc.cc --
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; sys.path.append('.')");
    // PyRun_SimpleString("print '\\n'.join(sys.path)");
    PyObject *pName = PyString_FromString("ttest");
    PyObject *pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    double arr[] ={9.74219, 10.2226, 8.7469, 8.69791, 9.96442, 9.96472, 9.37913, 9.75004};
    double arr1[] ={9.94227,9.46763,8.53081,9.43679,9.97695,10.4285,10.159,8.86134};

    PyObject *pArgs = PyTuple_New(3);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, PyLong_FromLong(8));
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, PyLong_FromVoidPtr(arr));
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 2, PyLong_FromVoidPtr(arr1));

    if (pModule != NULL) {
        PyObject *pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "blahptr");

        if(pFunc != NULL){
            PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Module path provided may be wrong. Module not found.\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and on the python side:

```
-- ttest.py --
from ctypes import POINTER, c_double, cast
c_double_p = POINTER(c_double)

import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

def blahptr(n, baseline_ptr, follow_up_ptr):
    baseline = np.ctypeslib.as_array(cast(baseline_ptr, c_double_p), shape=(n,))
    follow_up = np.ctypeslib.as_array(cast(follow_up_ptr, c_double_p), shape=(n,))
    return blah(baseline, follow_up)

def blah(baseline, follow_up):
    paired_sample  = stats.ttest_rel(baseline , follow_up )
    print "The t-statistic is %.3f and the p-value is %.3f." % paired_sample
    return paired_sample
```

In order to compile and run the code on Mac OS X I used the following:

```
$ PYENV=/path/to/python/env
$ c++ pyfromc.cc -I$PYENV/include/python2.7 -L$PYENV/lib -lpython2.7    
$ PYTHONHOME=$PYENV DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PYENV/lib ./a.out 
The t-statistic is -0.187 and the p-value is 0.857.
```

By setting the environment variables on the same line as the executable, the bash interpreter only sets them for the duration of the command and not for other commands.